# Deleting on multiple conditions in Prisma

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

So I understand that the where clause in Prisma needs a *unique* input in order to run its delete, but I have used the @@unique function to ensure that *multiple* conditions need to be columns together need to be unique. What I am struggling to understand is how to implement this when it comes to the delete functionality.

```js
model CommentDislike {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  comment    Comment  @relation(fields: [comment_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  comment_id Int
  user       User     @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  user_id    String
  created_at DateTime @default(now())

  @@unique([user_id, comment_id])
}
```

```
 try {
      prisma.commentLike.delete({
        where: {
          user_id: user_id,
          comment_id: comment_id,
        }
      })
    } catch (e: any) {
      console.log(e)
    }
```

This does not work.
Wanted to use the AND clause, but this does not work either.

Comment: delete() function only takes the unique id of the thing you are deleting, in this case, "id". You can either use findFirst() to find the commentLike with user and comment id and use delete() to delete it with the found id. You can also use deleteMany() to delete one field by using non unique fields

Answer (score 0):

If you have a compound id you can delete by supplying both as described here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/special-fields-and-types/working-with-composite-ids-and-constraints#deleting-records-by-a-compound-id-or-unique-constraint

```
const commentDislike = await prisma.commentDislike.delete({
  where: {
    userId_commentId: {
      userId: 1,
      commentId: 1,
    },
  },
})
```